# How to select with array values in comma separated values in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I'm not good at english so i appologise it for first.
I have an array value like this:

```
$a=['php','java','.Net']
```

please look at this link provided.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2c07a/4

How to make selection with the table.

Please help me guys...I thank you in advance...

Comment: use like query
 keyskills like "%java%" and keyskills like "%php%"

Comment: Your approach is not good. Storing structured data in a comma separated string, so _as a string_ will certainly lead to huge problems afterwards. Instead you should store the "skills" in a separate table that is referred to in a relational manner. That is how relational databases are meant to be used. _Then_ you can easily select the hits you are looking for.

Comment: @PrashantSrivastav Not a good advice. First it will show horrible performance, then you would also recommend javascript frontend guys for the backend java job.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `FIND_IN_SET`

PHP code:

```
$a=['php','java','.Net']
$query_part = '';
foreach($a as $v)
{
    $query_part .= "FIND_IN_SET('$v',keyskills) OR ";
}
$query_part = trim($query_part, ' OR ');

$sql = "select jobid from jobfair where $query_part";

//select jobid from jobfair where FIND_IN_SET('php',keyskills) OR FIND_IN_SET('java',keyskills) OR FIND_IN_SET('.Net',keyskills);
```

If you want to return rows that match all values then use `AND` clause.

Reference: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set